# Row data as column in time keeper

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server, row

I have data from table `CheckInOut`

```
select UserEnrollNumber,TimeDate,TimeStr from DATACHAMCONG.dbo.CheckInOut


UserEnrollNumber    TimeDate                 TimeStr

50559               2015-01-03 00:00:00.000  2015-01-03 07:21:32.000
50559               2015-01-03 00:00:00.000  2015-01-03 16:28:36.000
```

I want to display as:

```
UserEnrollNumber TimeDate    IN1                      OUT1                      IN2     OUT2   IN3     OUT3

50559            2014-01-03  2015-01-03 07:21:32.000  2014-01-03 17:11:22.000   NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL
```

what kind support for me?

Comment: Which database? Sql-Server or MySql? @
Dương Hồng Anh

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(UserEnrollNumber INT,TimeDate DATETIME,TimeStr DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 50559, '2015-01-03 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-03 07:21:32.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 50559, '2015-01-03 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-03 16:28:36.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 50559, '2015-01-04 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-04 07:15:32.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 50559, '2015-01-04 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-04 08:13:36.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 50559, '2015-01-04 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-04 09:28:36.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 50559, '2015-01-04 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-04 16:15:32.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 70987, '2015-01-03 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-03 04:08:32.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 70987, '2015-01-03 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-03 14:01:36.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 70987, '2015-01-05 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-05 06:18:32.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 70987, '2015-01-05 00:00:00.000',  '2015-01-05 15:21:36.000'
```

**QUERY**

I have written the logic inside the query.

```
SELECT UserEnrollNumber,CAST(TimeDate AS DATE)TimeDate,
TimeStr,[STATUS]+CAST(RNO AS VARCHAR(30))[STATUS],
-- Logic to order columns in pivot like IN1,OUT1,IN2,OUT2....
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY RNO,[STATUS]) ORG
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM
(
    SELECT  *,
    -- 1st record will be IN next OUT next IN next OUT.....
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserEnrollNumber ORDER BY UserEnrollNumber,TimeDate,TimeStr)%2 = 0 
    THEN 'OUT' ELSE 'IN' END [STATUS],
    -- Check the count of In-out in a date
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserEnrollNumber,CAST(TimeDate AS DATE) ORDER BY UserEnrollNumber,CAST(TimeDate AS DATE),TimeStr)+1)/2 RNO
    FROM #TEMP
)TAB
ORDER BY UserEnrollNumber,CAST(TimeDate AS DATE),TimeStr
```

Get the columns for dynamic pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [STATUS] + ']','[' + [STATUS] + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT ORG,[STATUS] FROM #NEWTABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY ORG
```

Now pivot the query

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT UserEnrollNumber,TimeDate, TimeStr,[STATUS]
                 FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(TimeStr)
                 FOR [STATUS] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY UserEnrollNumber,TimeDate' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80fa1/1) to see the working result**

Comment: I'm excute this query and recieve this error :

(16561 row(s) affected)

Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: Which is your database? SQL Server or MYSQL? @Dương Hồng Anh

Answer (score -1):

I'm excute this query and recieve this error :

(16561 row(s) affected)

Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.